# Function to identify records that are within 5 minute intervals

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL table with many records as shown in the image below.

[image]

I need to identify rows that are within 5 minute intervals for example, and mark each row in a new column that row is within 5 minutes. See the example of the output.

[image]

How can I do this through a function?

Comment: When 1st interval starts? When next 5-min interval starts - strongly start of previous interval + 5 minute or least time which is out of previous interval? And specify MySQL version.

Comment: The first 5-minute interval starts from the first record in the table. After the first interval of 5 minutes, the next interval begins, and so on.

The version of MYSQL is 8.

Answer (score 0):

Test

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT MIN(`datetime`) AS dt_start, 
                MIN(`datetime`) + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE AS dt_end,
                1 AS group_num
         FROM sourcetable
         UNION ALL
         SELECT dt_end,
                dt_end + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE,
                group_num + 1
         FROM cte
         WHERE dt_end <= ( SELECT MAX(`datetime`)
                           FROM sourcetable )
       )
SELECT sourcetable.*, cte.group_num
FROM sourcetable
JOIN cte ON `datetime` >= dt_start
        AND `datetime` < dt_end
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test and report the result.

Comment: @MarcelinoSantos If so mark your quesdtion as solved one.

Answer (score 0):

If your 5-minute intervals are based on calendar time, then the most efficient method would use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by to_seconds(floor(data / 300))) as tr
from t;
```

If it is based on when the first record within each group starts, then you need recursive CTEs as Akina suggests.

Comment: *If your 5-minute intervals are based on calendar time* OP says *The first 5-minute interval starts from the first record in the table.*. See comments.